# Has it been researched whether face centered cubic carbon is stable?

Tags: physical-properties-of-materials

According to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925963500004568#:%7E:text=A%20new%20carbon%20modification%20having,a%20metallic%20form%20of%20), carbon has a face centered cubic phase which is a metallic form. My question is:

**Has it been researched whether face centered cubic carbon is stable?**

Reasons why I'm interested in this question can be found in the edit history of this post.

Comment: Thinks, I think this was a good edit. I guess you have Matter Modelling Stack Exchange expertise that I don't have. I have to just trust your judgement because I cannot know how to make a question really good myself.

Comment: This SE is related to computational modeling of matter, not a Materials Science or Materials Chemistry SE. Therefore, I have voted to close this question as out of scope. @Timothy's questions do not belong on this SE.

Comment: I will admit, this is closer to being on topic than most other questions, but this is still the type of question which should be moved to Chemistry or Physics at the very least.

Comment: @TristanMaxson, yes, this question could be answered with modeling even if the question isn't about it directly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the papers citing the paper you linked is [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0008622304000545) : G. Murrieta, A. Tapia, and R. de Coss, Structural stability of carbon in the face-centered-cubic (Fm$\bar{3}$m) phase, Carbon **4**, 771-774 (2004). It concludes with:

> "In order to evaluate the structural stability of the fcc
> phase of carbon, we have calculated the total energy as a function of the isotropic, tetragonal, and trigonal
> deformations for bulk fcc carbon using the full-potential
> LAPW method. We find that the total energy shows a
> minimum for the isotropic deformation, but exhibits
> maxima for the tetragonal and trigonal deformations.
> This means that the bulk fcc structure is not a true
> metastable phase of carbon. It is likely that the interaction with the substrate and impurities contribute to
> stabilize the fcc structure in the existing fcc carbon thin
> films on diamond. However, the exact nature of these
> interactions remains unknown."

If you're interested, I would recommend further exploring the citation tree. There seems to be other studies addressing the structure and stability also from an experimental perspective.